# Build a semicolon separated string for a People/Group sharepoint field which allow multiple selection from GetItems action

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

We have this Capital Request Setting SharePoint custom list >> which contain a Tile field and a People/Group field (which allow multiple selection named Person):

[image]

and inside our Power Automate we are getting all items from this list >> then we need to build a semicolon string for all the user emails for the item which have it's title = "Board of Directors". Is this possible using union and select?

I do not want to define an "Apply To each" if I can do it directly using Select & Union? Any advice?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using Select action. Use person or group column as input to the select action and then map email field. Then you can use the Email array to build a single string.

Comment: Are you adding filter query based on Title column value in Get items action? If you need only one row from the list, you should do it. Or are you using other items as well from this list in the flow?

Comment: @Ganesh Sanap but i need to filter the items based on the Title =="Board of Directors" first. i am getting all items inside the GetItems since i will need to build multiple semicollon strings based on the Titles

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Power automate flow like this:

[image]

**Expressions used**:

**Select Action**:

- From: `@{first(body('Filter_array'))?['Person']}`
- Map: `@item()?['Email']` - Switch map to text mode before adding this expression

Where `Person` is internal name of your person or group column. You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Compose Action**:

```
@{join(body('Select'),';')}
```

**List data**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: worked thanks...